# Flat a list based on property in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I have a list of custom objects which look as follows:

```
listOf(MyItem(1, listOf("Aus","Ame")), MyItem(2, listOf("Cha", "Tel")))
```

MyItem class:

```
data class MyItem(val num: Int, val list: List<String>)
```

I want to expand the list as below based on the property of `code` in `MyItem` class:

```
listOf(MyItem(1, listOf("Aus")), MyItem(1, listOf("Ame")), MyItem(2, listOf("Cha")), MyItem(2, listOf("Tel")))
```

How can achieve this?

Comment: I'm not close to a pc so I can't tell you the exact syntax, but what you can do is first pass the first list thorough a flatMap to generate a Pair<int,String> and then through a map to create the MyItem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `flatMap` and then another `map` inside.

```
val input = listOf(MyItem(1, listOf("Aus","Ame")), MyItem(2, listOf("Cha", "Tel")))
val result = input.flatMap { item -> item.list.map { item.copy(list = listOf(it)) } }
println(result)
// listOf(MyItem(1, listOf("Aus")), MyItem(1, listOf("Ame")), MyItem(2, listOf("Cha")), MyItem(2, listOf("Tel")))
```